map one column value to another column in python dataframe
I have a dataframe with below columns in it -
id|title|
23|xyz|
34|kij|
123|hyu|
45|NaN|
345|None|

I want new column in it , expected output -
id|title|url
23|xyz|https://www.cl.com/23/xyz
34|kij|https://www.cl.com/34/kij
123|hyu|https://www.cl.com/123/hyu
45|NaN|NaN
345|None|None

I tried below code , but no luck -
df['url'] = "https://www.cl.com/" + str(df['id']) + '/' + str(df['title'])

But it gives same row for all the dataframe.
Any help would be appreciated.

Use .astype(str) not str(df[...])
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """id|title
23|xyz
34|kij
123|hyu
45|
345|"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='|')
df['url'] = "https://www.cl.com/" + df['id'].astype(str) + '/' + df['title']


    id title                         url
0   23   xyz   https://www.cl.com/23/xyz
1   34   kij   https://www.cl.com/34/kij
2  123   hyu  https://www.cl.com/123/hyu
3   45   NaN                         NaN
4  345   NaN                         NaN

